# Cómo añadir excepciones a un módulo?

Tags: java, mvc

¿Como puedo colocar excepciones en este Modulo, un ejemplo es que en el txtField de Cedula, como solo es con números, colocar una excepción ahi? mvc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Problemas con excepciones:
Tengo que colocar una excepción en el campo de cedula, si el usuario coloca letras en ese campo deberia de lanzar una excepcion que me diga que no debe de hacerlo

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 1):

Si el valor de entrada en el campo cédula es de tipo `String` puedes hacer uso de un bloque try-catch, por ejemplo:

```
        try {
            Integer.parseInt("valor_en_el_campo_cedula".trim());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //muestra un mensaje: solo se admiten valores numéricos
        }
```